# Java, program that counts random number and saves it

Tags: java, arrays, random, count

I am trying to make a program that lets the user choose how many times he want to throw the dice, and then every value of the thrown dice should be counted. In the end of the program the user should see how many times he threw 1, 2, 3 etc. This is a program to see if every number has an equal chance of being shown.

I encountered problems in the beginning of my code since I don't know how to let the computer throw the dice lets say 1000 times and then save every value from those thrown dices. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uppgift4_5 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("How many times do you want to throw the dice:");
    int amount = inputReader.nextInt();

    int [] dice = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int random = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        random = (int) (Math.random () + 1);
    }





}
```

}

The problem I'm facing is that it only saves one random number and then loops that number 6 times.
As you can see I have not come far, I just need to know how I can save and count every individual thrown dice. And then I think I am going to use a switch and case to somehow save that(any suggestions there would also be helpful). Any suggestions or answers would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a HashMap to store the value of the throw (1 to 6), as well as storing the number of times you got that value (increment by one for each):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many times do you want to throw the dice:");
    int amount = inputReader.nextInt();

    Map<Integer, Integer> rolls = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        rolls.put(i, 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        int value = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        rolls.put(value, rolls.get(value) + 1);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : rolls.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

The first for-loop initializes the keys 1 to 6 in the hashmap.

The second for-loop computes X number of dice throws and adds them to the hashmap.

The third for-loop iterates through the values in the hashmap and prints out the results.

Output:

```
How many times do you want to throw the dice:
500
1: 92
2: 88
3: 72
4: 78
5: 81
6: 89
```

**EDIT:** If you want to get the average and the median you could do the following:

```
double average = 0;
int[] storedSums = new int[6];

int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : rolls.entrySet()) {
    int sum = entry.getValue();
    average += sum;
    storedSums[i++] = sum;
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + sum);
}

Arrays.sort(storedSums);

System.out.println("Average: " + (average / 6));
System.out.println("Median: " + storedSums[2]);
```

The average is simply the process of summing the values and dividing by the amount. The median with a hashmap is a little bit more tricky, however. The better choice here is to use an Array or an ArrayList to store the different values, then sort them and finally pick the middle element (either index 2 or 3).

I opted for an array in this case because we know the size of it.

**EDIT:** Regarding your last request:

To get the dice the median value corresponds to, I simply convert the array to a list, and use the indexOf method with the known value:

```
int medianDice = Arrays.asList(storedSums).indexOf(storedSums[2]);
System.out.println("Median: " + storedSums[2] + ", which belongs to dice: " + medianDice + ".");
```

It's a bit more complicated to get the value of the dice for the average (since this number isn't represented by one of the dies). You would have to use the average to find the closest value in the array, and then output the index for that value.

Comment: Would you also know how I can easily get the median and the average when I use this solution?

Comment: @mackanmorre Sure thing! I've updated the answer :) Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks! There seems to be one problem though. The median and average are returned as the value 1?

Comment: @mackanmorre, The average and the median for (let's say) 10 throws are very likely to be one. If you want a more "correct" value, you can set the average to be a double instead of an integer. The more dice throws, the higher the value for both the average and median gets.

Comment: And if you still have any time left, one problem I have is that when I do like 500 throws, the average and median gets the value 80. Instead i want the average and the median to range from 1-6.

Comment: @mackanmorre, Alright! I've updated the post with some additional information :) Hint: Index of closest value for the average.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an `ArrayList` to store the random numbers and later process it when needed.

```
List<Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>(amount);
Random generator = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
     listOfNumbers.add(generator.nextInt(7));
}
```

Also, your current algorithm for the random numbers is incorrect, you should use the `Random` class to generator random numbers between `1 - 6` (inclusive).

Comment: @austinwernli there is already another answer regarding that, so i'll stick with this ^^.

Answer (score 1):

You are over writing the same `random` `int` value again and again, so use an array of `int` to store the values as shown below:

```
int[] random = new int[amount];//declare an array
Random randomNumber =  new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    random[i] = randomNumber.nextInt(7);
}
```

Also, use [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) `nextInt()` with an upper bound (in your case, the max value for the dice can be 6, so use upper bound as 7) to generate the random numbers as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many times do you want to roll the dice:");
    int num_rolls = inputReader.nextInt();
    int NUM_SIDES_ON_DICE = 6;
    int[] results = new int[NUM_SIDES_ON_DICE]
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rolls; i++) {
        results[rand.nextInt(NUM_SIDES_ON_DICE)] += 1
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number of " + (i+1) + "'s thrown: " + results[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Version with stream:

```
        new Random()
        .ints(amount, 1, 7).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": "+v.size()));;
```